# Unordered_map using pointer address as key

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap, unordered-map

I'm trying to create a map with a custom key, which is an object's pointer address, as mentioned.

I need the address because for now it's the only relevant way to compare between two objects.

from what i understood, the proper way of doing this is by using `const char*` as key

here is the `typedef` :

```
typedef __gnu_cxx::unordered_map<const char*, std::string> TargetsTags;
```

I'm  a bit confused about the following:

how do I create the `operator()` ?

This is what i used for `std::string`:

```
namespace __gnu_cxx {
    template<>
    struct hash<std::string>
    {
        hash<const char*> h;
        size_t operator()(const std::string &s) const
        {
            return h(s.c_str());
        };
    };
}
```

What about `const char*`?

And is this the correct way of doing this?

Comment: You notice those two leading underscores in `__gnu_cxx`? That basically means it's a *private* symbol. If your compiler and standard library is to old for C++11, then use the `std::tr1` namespace and its header files, and if your compiler and library doesn't event support TR1, then use Boost.

Comment: As for the use of pointers as key, don't. Even if you have two strings that points to memory that are the same in each and every way, except that they are two different allocations, then it wont work. The hashing is done on the *pointers* and not what they point to.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks for the comment, but i must use the pointers as keys for now. as for the `__gnu_cxx`, you are right.

Comment: you always can supply to unordered_map your own hash and equals functions that will convert const char * to a string like: `__gnu_cxx::unordered_map<const char*, std::string, myhashtype, myequalstype>` (if it works as in c++11 not sure how is it implemented in your compiler, but as you try to work with `hash<std::string>` my feeling tells me it is a good direction)...

Answer (score 5):

The working example using c++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class myhash {
public:
   size_t operator() (const char *val) const {
      return std::hash<std::string>()(val);
   }
};

class myequal {
public:
   bool operator()(const char *val1, const char *val2) const{
      return std::string(val1) == std::string(val2);
   }
};



int main() {

   std::unordered_map<const char*, string, myhash, myequal> mymap;
   mymap["abc"] = "abcd";
   mymap["cba"] = "dcba";
   std::cout << mymap["abc"] << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```